# How to Disable SSL in Windows 8 Tablet to Connect Exchange ActiveSync

Tags: windows, email, exchange, tablet, activesync

Okay this is what I think would be a simple question that no-one seems to have answers for, I purchased a new Windows 8 Tablet, a Dell Latitude 10 to be exact, I've already talked to Dell and MS about this. My Exchange doesn't support SSL on our Android/iPhone mobile devices you can turn off SSL when setting up the ActiveSync or at least save the account and go into Advanced settings and change it after the fact, this Windows Mail native app does NOT let you disable SSL or save the account to turn it off later. Online it shows that once the account is created you can go into the account settings and turn off SSL but not during the initial setup. There has to be a way to setup a non-SSL Exchange account on this thing. Please help I need to get this setup ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: Why not turn on and use SSL on the Exchange server?

Comment: Any luck with this ? If I go back to the settings after creating the account, there is a "Server requires SSL" checkbox but it is greyed out.